# Create bean in xml from method

Tags: java, spring

I have a class MyFactory which can create MyClass:

```
package com.mypackage
@Component
public class MyFactory{  
    @Bean
    public MyClass createMyClass() {
        return // magic class creation... ;
    }
}
```

How to use that method to create a bean with xml?

```
<bean  id="myClass" factory-method="com.mypackage.MyFactory.createMyClass"/>
```

doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `@Bean` annotation from the factory method:

```
package com.mypackage;

@Component
public class MyFactory{  
    public MyClass createMyClass() {
        return // magic class creation... ;
    }
}
```

And then in XML:

```
<bean id="myClass" factory-bean="myFactory" factory-method="createMyClass"/>
```

If you also want the factory to be configured via XML, then remove the `@Component` annotation from class `MyFactory` and create it in XML as well:

```
<bean id="myFactory" class="com.mypackage.MyFactory"/>

<bean id="myClass" factory-bean="myFactory" factory-method="createMyClass"/>
```

See the documentation: [Instantiation by Using an Instance Factory Method](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method)